# Is there a joint distribution for binary and continuous variables?

Tags: probability-distributions

As an example, let's imagine that we have the following four variables measured in 500 people:

*H* - height in centimeters

*W* - weight in kilograms

*B* - whether the person is a member of a basketball team (binary variable)

*S* - whether the person is a member of a sumo wrestling club (binary variable)

Is there a joint distribution for *H*, *W*, *B* and *S*?

Comment: Of course. But I would assume the distribution you mean a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^4$ where the $(H,W,B,S)$ takes value. 
\begin{align*}
\mu(A_1\times A_2\times A_3\times A_4) = P(H\in A_1, W\in A_2,B\in A_3, S\in A_4) 
\end{align*}
where $A_i$ are 'measurable' sets in $\mathbb{R}$. 
However the joint distribution might not be the product probability measure. The joint probability measure I think should always exist

Answer (score 0):

Of course.
The support of the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ can be pretty much "any" subset of ${\mathbb R}^2$, for example, $\{0,1\}\times {\mathbb R}$, if which case $X$ is Bernouilli and $Y$ can be continuous.

Comment: But what would be the parameters of that distribution, given that the Bernoulli distribution and e.g. the normal distribution don't have the same parameters?

Comment: The parameters can be anything

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not helpful

Comment: The parameter of Bernoulli distribution p can be any number between 0 and 1. The parameters of normal can be e.g. any positive numbers. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clearer. You are speaking now about the parameters of these univariate distributions, Bernoulli and normal. You are furthermore speaking not about the parameters themselves, but about which values they support. For example, the parameters of the normal distribution are called the mean and the standard deviation. My question is what would be the names of the parameters of this joint distribution of continuous and binary variables - they can't be the mean and the standard deviation because the binary variables in the joint distribution wouldn't support that

Comment: As far as I am aware, there are no specific "names" of such mixed distributions; you can find a list of common distributions in many books/internet, but they usually are either jointly continuous or jointly discrete. What I am saying is that you *can* have a joint distribution which does not belong to either of these two classes, it's just it wouldn't have an "established" name.